# Get all teachers that have at least 1 subject on table - Django Query Set

Tags: python, django

I Would like to get all the Teachers that have at least 1 subject. Currently I'm using...

```
user = users.objects.all().order_by('-karma')[:100]
```

Because people who does not have any subjects related is a Student.

Here is my *models.py*

```
class subjects(models.Model):
    id_user = models.IntegerField(db_column='ID_user') # Field name made lowercase.
    s = models.CharField(max_length=90)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.s

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'subjects'


class users(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=160)
    nick = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=60)
    karma = models.IntegerField(max_length=11)
    pass_field = models.CharField(db_column='pass', max_length=160)
```

Comment: It looks like that the models are not related (`id_user` is just an `IntegerField`, not a `ForeignKey`). Is it intentional?

Comment: this is a reverse Database Model. Gets generated automaticaly by Django this database exists already with current data.

Comment: Just want to get all the users that have at least 1 row inserted on model subject

Comment: I used select related user.objects.select_related('subjects').order_by('-karma')[:100] but still shows users that does not have any subjects in it.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to do this in two steps:

- get `id_user` list from subjects model with the help of [`values_list()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list):

  ```
  user_ids = subjects.objects.values_list('id_user', flat=True).distinct()
  ```
- get all users by the list of `id_user`s using [`__in`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#the-pk-lookup-shortcut):

  ```
  print users.objects.filter(pk__in=user_ids)
  ```

Also, since models are not related, you can make a [`raw` query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/) that would do the same in one go.

Comment: @eddwinpaz if performance doesn't really matter here, I would leave it as is. Otherwise, consider making a raw SQL query. In other words, do it without using the power of django ORM.